# Android UI layout component resizing wrongly on font size change

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have a layout with 3 components that align perfectly as long as the user doesn't change the font size in display settings on their android phones...
One this happens, the UI elements fail to align properly..My best guess is that it has something to do with Layout weight.

As you can see, CSR mentions gets pushed slightly below..

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/r"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/div"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@color/nliveo_white"
            android:padding="@dimen/pad">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/recshape"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Direct Mentions"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sz" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dir"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="164"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rec2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rec2shape"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Industry Mentions"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sz" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idm"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="30"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rec3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rec3shape"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:text="CSR Mentions"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_sz" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/csr"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="14"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the units used when defining the text sizes.

I guess your dimension defined by @dimen/txt_sz is in sp, like the number of the blue square and as you can  see those are the only ones reacting to the user change.

Change the text sizes to sp and everything should be fixed.

> Scale-independent Pixels (sp) this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If the text size is given in 'sp' its a normal behaviour. 
Have a look at the definition of SP in docs.

> Scale-independent Pixels - This is like the dp unit, but it is also
>   scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use
>   this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and the user's preference.

You may use 'dp' instead depending upon your logic.